# (64 Yogini Stotram) Can we recite the Namavalli of just one of them?

Tags: mantras, stotra

As the title, can we chant the naam mantra of one of them, instead of chanting all of them one by one from No.1 to No.64? There may be mistakes in the mantra of some Yogini-s, and you want to be a bhakta of one of them, why don't we pick one of them whose mantra is correct and chant it more than once(e.g. 108 times) daily?
For example, Om virodhini vilAsinyai namah ?